# Erro no cálculo da média a partir de dados do inmet usando um programa em Fortran

Tags: fortran

Estou iniciando no Fortran, e montei o seguinte programa para obter a média da 4º coluna de dados de um arquivo de dados do INMET. Sendo que a média calculada está sendo 0 (zero). Alguém poderia me dizer onde está o erro no programa?

```
program inmet

implicit none

integer, parameter    :: M=760, N=18   !Há 760 linhas e 18 colunas
character (4)         :: id            !Diz que o numero da estação é um string, com 4 itens.
real, dimension (M,N) :: dados         !Declaração de matriz
integer               :: i
real                  :: media

open(10,file="inmet.txt",status="old",access="sequential",action="read")
open(20,file="inmet_media_out.txt",status="replace",access="sequential",action="write")

do i = 1,M
   read(10,*) id, dados(i,:)
end do

media = sum(dados (:,4))/real(M)

write(20,'(a,f6.2)') "A média de temperaturas é", media

end program
```

Um exemplo do inicío do arquivo txt do INMET segue abaixo (delimitado por virgulas), e a primeira coluna é o código de estação meteorológica:

```
A250,17/07/2018,23,25.4,26.6,25.4,75,85,73,20.6,23.3,20.3,995.5,995.5,994.8,1.2,81,7.1,-3.09,0.0
A250,17/07/2018,22,26.1,27.6,26.1,84,84,72,23.2,23.4,22.1,994.8,994.8,994.7,0.4,103,2.0,51.86,0.0
A250,17/07/2018,21,27.6,30.0,27.6,73,75,63,22.5,23.8,22.1,994.7,995.1,994.5,0.8,85,5.2,648.0,0.0
A250,17/07/2018,20,30.0,30.5,29.9,63,66,62,22.2,23.1,21.9,995.1,995.1,994.9,2.4,107,5.7,1875.,0.0
A250,17/07/2018,19,30.0,30.3,29.7,64,67,62,22.4,23.3,21.9,995.0,995.7,994.9,2.0,108,5.5,2382.,0.0
A250,17/07/2018,18,29.8,30.3,29.6,66,70,63,22.8,23.7,22.0,995.7,996.6,995.7,2.2,103,5.5,2763.,0.0
A250,17/07/2018,17,30.1,30.4,29.3,67,69,63,23.4,23.9,22.1,996.6,997.5,996.6,2.1,104,6.0,3128.,0.0
A250,17/07/2018,16,29.4,29.7,28.9,67,72,65,22.6,23.5,22.3,997.5,998.1,997.4,2.3,109,6.0,3143.,0.0
```

E a minha saída (em txt) está saindo assim:

```
A média de temperaturas é  0.00
```

Desde já agradeço quem puder me iluminar

Answer (score 1):

Um dos problemas está no comando `read(10,*)`, pois o `*` indica que você está fazendo uma leitura de direcionada a lista (*list-directed*), e este tipo de leitura não é o ideal para os dados da pergunta devido aos tipos de dados diferentes (*string* e números).

Outro problema é que você está tentando ler a data (tipo *string*) para a primeira posição do array `dados`, que é um tipo *real* (incompatível).

Uma forma possível (e simples) para solucionar esses problemas, é declarar uma variável para armazenar a data (tipo `character (len=10)`):

```
character (len=10)    :: dt          ! a data
```

e, no comando `read`, indicar a formatação conforme os dados do arquivo:

```
read(10,'(a4,1x,a10,1x,f6.0,3f6.1,3f6.0,7f6.1,f6.0,3f6.3)') id, dt, dados(i,:)
```

O programa alterado fica assim (com a variável *M* alterada para 8, conforme os dados da pergunta):

```
program inmet

    implicit none

    integer, parameter    :: M=8, N=18   !Há 760 linhas e 18 colunas
    character (len=4)     :: id          !Diz que o numero da estação é um string, com 4 itens.
    character (len=10)    :: dt          !a data
    real, dimension (M,N) :: dados       !Declaração de matriz
    integer               :: i
    real                  :: media

    open(10,file="inmet.txt",status="old",access="sequential",action="read")
    open(20,file="inmet_media_out.txt",status="replace",access="sequential",action="write")

    do i = 1,M
       read(10,'(a4,1x,a10,1x,f6.0,3f6.1,3f6.0,7f6.1,f6.0,3f6.3)') id, dt, dados(i,:)
    end do

    media = sum(dados (:,4))/real(M)

    write(20,'(a,f6.2)') "A média de temperaturas é", media

end program inmet
```

Após a execução, o arquivo de saída `inmet_media_out.txt` contém o resultado (para os dados informados na pergunta):

```
A média de temperaturas é 28.31
```

Uma outra forma, caso a formatação dos dados não seja estável, seria ler a linha inteira como string e depois separar o campos (*parser*) com o comando [`index`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INDEX-intrinsic.html).